# What does the -met ending mean in "vosmet" or "temet"

Tags: vocabulary, pronouns, suffixes, reflexive-pronoun

I don't understand where *vosmet* and *temet* came from. I know *vos* and *te* as pronouns, but what is the *-met* ending? Is that from some other language? Is it used anywhere else? It seems irregular. Why even use these words instead of the regular form for yourself (*ipsum*)?

Comment: One theory is it comes from the ablative of *egō*, which was originally *mēt/mēd*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's for emphasis, and older than the use of *ipse* as an intensifier. From Allen & Greenough §143.d:

> Emphatic forms of **tu** are **tute** and **tutemet** (**tutimet**). The other cases of the personal pronouns, excepting the genitive plural, are made emphatic by adding **-met**: as, **egomet**, **vosmet**.
>   NOTE.—Early emphatic forms are **mepte** and **tepte**.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Latin_words_suffixed_with_-met) has a list of them all.

You can stack them, too: [*egomet ipse*](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/426/1/53/685-696#53).

Comment: It might be worth to note that Greek has an analogous construct involving the ubiquitous clitic γε: the form ἔγωγε is used as an intensified version of ἐγώ. Frequently, one also sees the forms ἔμοιγε for ἐμοί, σύγε for σύ, and sometimes ἐμοῦγε and ἐμέγε. Notice the recessive accent on ἔγωγε and ἔμοιγε. (vide Smyth 325 d)